# Sequalize join multiple model giving alias error

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

Hello guys I am new to sequalize and I am facing difficulty to join multiple tables.

Sequalize throws error below:

```
SequelizeEagerLoadingError: customers is associated to estimations using an alias. You've included an alias (createdby_details), but it does not match the alias(es) defined in your association (customer_details).
```

Here is my Estimation model:

```
var Customer = require('../models/Customer')
var User = require('../models/User')

var Estimations = connection.sequelize.define('estimations',{
    id:{
        type: connection.Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    user_id: {
        type: connection.Sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    title: {
        type: connection.Sequelize.TEXT
    },
    customer_id: {
        type: connection.Sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    project_address: {
        type: connection.Sequelize.TEXT
    },
    bid: {
        type: connection.Sequelize.TEXT
    },
    due_date: {
        type: connection.Sequelize.DATEONLY
    },
    total_cost: {
        type: connection.Sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    created_by: {
        type: connection.Sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    is_deleted: {
        type: connection.Sequelize.TINYINT
    },
    created_at: {
        type: connection.Sequelize.DATE
    },
    updated_at: {
        type: connection.Sequelize.DATE
    }
},{
    timestamps: true,
    createdAt: 'created_at',
    updatedAt: 'updated_at'
});

Estimations.belongsTo(Customer, {
    as: 'customer_details',
    foreignKey: 'customer_id',
    targetKey: 'id'
});

Estimations.belongsTo(User, {
    as: 'createdby_details',
    foreignKey: 'created_by',
    targetKey: 'id'
});
```

Here is my controller code:

```
EstimationSchema.findAndCountAll({
                    include: [ 
                        {
                            attributes: ['org_name'],
                            model: CustomerSchema,
                            as: "customer_details"
                        },
                        {
                            attributes: ['first_name'],
                            model: UserSchema,
                            as: "createdby_details"
                        }
                    ],
                    attributes: columnName,
                    where: whereobj,
                    limit: parseInt(req.body.length),
                    offset: parseInt(req.body.start),
                    order: [ sort ]
                }).then(records => {
                    response.recordsTotal = records.count;
                    response.recordsFiltered = records.count
                    response.data = records.rows

                }).catch(err => {

                })
```

I have one another model 'User' which has primary key 'id' and it has to match with my above 'Estimation' model with 'created_by' field and fetch that user data.

What I want to do is to fetch 'Estimation' table data with associated 'Customer' and 'User' table data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `UserSchema`? Where are you defining this?

Comment: it is other model where user related table defination are.

Comment: check `UserSchema` = require('')`; Error says alias you specified is `createdby_details` but relationship defines as `customer_details`. To me, it looks like `UserSchema` is swapped with `CustomerSchema`.

Comment: let me take a look